# Update mongo array elements field from its other field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo-3.x

Let's assume following document

```
{
    "companies": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "Company 1", "new_name": "New company 1"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "Company 2", "new_name": "New company 2"}
    ]
}
```

Is there a way I can reference element of array by itself to migrate to scheme

```
{
    "companies": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "New company 1", "new_name": "New company 1"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "New company 2", "new_name": "New company 2"}
    ]
}
```

within a single call to `update` without scripting with `forEach` in mongo 4.2?
Something like

```
update(
...
{
  "companies.$[].name": "$companies.<???>.new_name"
}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access another field's value in a query you need to use aggregation, taking advantage of executing aggregation pipeline in [.update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline)'s which got introduced in MongoDB version `4.2`, try below query :

```
update(
    ...
    [
        {
          $addFields: { // will replace existing field with new value
            companies: {
              $map: { // Iterates on an array & creates a new one
                input: "$companies",
                in: { $mergeObjects: [ "$$this", { name: "$$this.new_name" } ] } // `mergeObjects` will merge two objects `name` field will be replace in current object i.e; `$$this`
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    )
```

**Test :** You can test aggregation pipeline here : [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PDda7FI0Igz)

**Note :** Seems to be using aggregation is only option to do this in one call, but downside could be only if your array is too huge, cause `$map` has to re-write entire array again.